# Acrobat Reader DC trusted folder options

Tags: acrobat

I need to add a local path as a trusted path for the acrobat reader DC so that a file in that path can be accessed through a link in the PDF.

I need to add this path as trusted folder through registry and not through the user interface of the acrobat reader. I have tried the following registry keys:

1. `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Wow6432Node\Adobe\Acrobat Reader\2015\TrustManager\cTrustedFolders\` with all its subkeys and all keys had unique ID’s.
2. `[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Adobe\<product name>\<version>\TrustManager\cTrustedFolders\cCrossdomain]
   "t3"="C:\\Documents and Settings\\username\\My Documents\\acrobat_logo16.png"`

But neither worked.
Could anyone tell if trusted paths can be added only through registry settings?

Comment: Are you trying to open the PNG in Reader or import it as a button appearance? Even with a trusted folder, Reader can't open a PNG.

Comment: Thanks for your reply!!I am trying to open a bmp image. Through a link in the PDF. I  am able to open the link if I set the registry HKLM\Software\Policies\Adobe\Acrobat Reader\2015\FeatureLockDown to 0. This enables the UI which gives a chance for anyone to modify the trusted folders. So I want some other registry settings to do the same thing.

Comment: Do you mean open the image using the default Windows image viewer by clicking on a link in the PDF or open the image in Reader?